# How to load page after countdown finished in javascript

Tags: javascript, countdown

I have this code :

```
<h1 id="countdown-holder"></h1> 
<script>  
    var clock = document.getElementById("countdown-holder")  
    , targetDate = new Date(2050, 00, 01); // Jan 1, 2050;  

    clock.innerHTML = countdown(targetDate).toString();  
    setInterval(function(){  
        clock.innerHTML = countdown(targetDate).toString();  
    }, 1000);  
</script>
```

How can i load page after countdown finish ??

Comment: Have the page already loaded but hide the content. After the 36 years, just show content

Answer (score 1):

This is exact what you need

```
var now = Date.now();
if (now >= targetDate) {
    window.location = './target/url';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not described your "countdown" function here, we can assume that you can match when the countdown finish. Use the following code when your countdown finish:

```
window.location.replace("Page URL");
```